# How to read Rails development db in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application connects to an external, readonly, dataset which is accessed by frequently rotating keys.

That is, every few hours, your current key goes state, and then you need to use the refresh key to get a new access key.  When you use the refresh key, you get a new refresh key and a new access key.

The problem is in test, I have to get hold of these keys in order to run some of my tests.  Right now I am resorting to cut and pasting the current keys from my development.db where the keys are stored, into application.yml every couple of hours, but that of course is tedious.

I would like to read my development db to get the current set of keys as I start my testing session.

How to do that? (Rails 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an second connection configuration and manually create a connection within the model class.

```
# database.yaml
test_external:
...same as development

# production_external.yml
...your production keys storage


class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_external"
end
```

Or, if you don't want to change your model you can access the connection directly:

```
# rails_helper.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')
@@keys = ActiveRecord.Base.connection.execute('query to retrieve the keys')

# set connection again to test to not break the tests.
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.establish_connection(Rails.env)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have to do some small adjustments to make it work for rails 5.2: First, it should be `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.establish_connection` for rails 5.2. 2. Second, I have to use symbols as the environment name instead of strings, ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection.